# I have been awarded the Yearling badge twice in less than 2 years

Tags: discussion, badges, yearling-badge

I have been a user in stackoverflow for 518 days. And today I got my second yearling badge!
Is there something wrong with the way this badge been given or the badge documentation is wrong?

> Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have been a member for two years. You've just visited the site that number of days.

Comment: Does second yearling badge don't give 100 reps?